How to check if a specific string exists in a semicolon-separated registry value in NSIS and append it if not?
I have retrieved a string from the registry using NSIS that contains several semicolons as separators, for example: ABC;123;XYZ. I want to check if a specific substring, let's say "123", exists within this string. If it does exist, I don't want to perform any action. However, if the substring does not exist (for example, if I check for "qwe"), I need to append it to the end of the original string and then write the updated value back to the registry.
Here's a clear example:
Original registry value: ABC;123;XYZ
Specific string: "123" → No action needed.
Specific string: "qwe" → Update the value to ABC;123;XYZ;qwe.

Just to make sure, are you trying to change %Path% or is this something unrelated?

If you want to update the %PATH% environment variable you must use the EnVar plug-in.
Otherwise, you have to do some of the work yourself:
!include WordFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
Var Find

Section

StrCpy $1 "ABC;123;XYZ" ; ReadRegStr ...

StrCpy $Find "123"
${WordFind} $1 ";" "/$Find" $0
${If} $0 = $1
    DetailPrint '$Find not found in $1'
${Else}
    DetailPrint '$Find is string #$0 in $1'
${EndIf}

StrCpy $Find "qwe"
${WordFind} $1 ";" "/$Find" $0
${If} $0 = $1
    DetailPrint '$Find not found in $1'
    ${WordAdd} $1 ";" "+$Find" $1
    DetailPrint 'WriteRegStr ... $1'
${Else}
    DetailPrint '$Find is string #$0 in $1'
${EndIf}

SectionEnd

